# DbNull always coming back as a return value from SQL Server stored procedure in C# Spring.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, spring.net

I have a simple stored procedure that only returns the number 100 right now. Executing it from C# gives me `DBNull` when I check the returnvalue parameter when debugging. I know my stored procedure to just return 100 is nonsensical but my real logic was experiencing the same error, so I changed it to be the simplest version of what I'm trying to do to figure out how to get a decimal in C# from a return value of my stored procedure.

The specific exception I'm getting (location of exception noted below) is `System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.`

I have only changed names in my code below.

I have the following C# code

```
public class MyDataContext : AdoDaoSupport, IMyDataContext
{
    //Injected from web.config via spring.NET 
    // sp_GetOneHundred
    public string GetOneHundredProc { get; set; }

    public void Process(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            //Call Stored Procedure
            CallGetOneHundredStoredProcedure(name);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw;
        }
   } 
   private bool CallGetOneHundredStoredProcedure(string name)
   {
        IDbParameters parameters = CreateDbParameters();
        parameters.Add("Name", DbType.String, 254).Value = name;
        var returnValue = parameters.Add("return_value", DbType.Int32);
        returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        try
        {
           var  x = AdoTemplate.ExecuteNonQuery(
                   CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                   GetOneHundredProc,
                   parameters);


           return Convert.ToDecimal(returnValue.Value) == 1;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Exception thrown here
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

And the following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetOneHundred]
    @Name varchar(254)      
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;


   DECLARE @oneHundred AS Int;
   SET @oneHundred=100;
   RETURN @oneHundred;
END;
```

Edit: for fun I tried to do this and got a different exception:

```
 return Convert.ToDecimal(parameters["return_value"].Value) == 1;
```

The new exception I receive is

```
 System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'return_value' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.
```

Maybe that could help someone figure out what is happening

Comment: Do not start procedure names with `sp_`. This prefix is reserved for system stored procedures. If that doesn't sound bad enough, [consider that it's bad for performance](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: @sgeddes `OUTPUT` is different than `RETURN`

Comment: I don't immediately see where the problem in your code is -- the issue might be in `AdoTemplate.ExecuteNonQuery`, if it's not exactly like `SqlCommand`. Even if it works, though, keep in mind that a stored procedure can only return a single integer as a return value, and so this is usually of limited value -- pretty much all it's good for is a status condition, and error conditions are much better raised with `THROW` or `RAISERROR`. Actual results are better served with `SELECT` result sets and/or output parameters.

Comment: Your code can't compile because your method is `void` but you  return `Convert.ToDecimal(returnValue.Value) == 1;`

Comment: I would bet that spring.net makes new parameters for the command it creates so `returnValue` is not the one that gets set by command that actually executes. Check if `returnValue` ReferenceEquals the same parameter in `parameters` after execution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jeoreon.  D-Shih that was a typo.  Crowcoder I will look into that.  Thanks

Comment: Crowcoder, when doing `object.ReferenceEquals(returnValue, parameters["return_value"])`, I receive the following exception: `An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'return_value' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.`  Does that information help you at all or give you another suggestion I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone ever finds this same problem, I found the answer.  All I had to do was include the @ sign before my parameter name when checking the value

```
return Convert.ToDecimal(parameters["@return_value"].Value) == 1;
```

Note that I did not modify the line defining the parameter, there is no @ sign there.

```
var returnValue = parameters.Add("return_value", SqlDbType.Int);
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```